# how to get previous and next menu item in knp menu?

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I am using knp menu bundle to generate tree menu. How do I get previous and next menu item (to navigate to previous and next post like in blog) with respect to current opened page ?

Answer (score 0):

As [menu items extend ArrayAccess](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/blob/master/src/Knp/Menu/ItemInterface.php) you can get the previous/next item the same way as you'd do with a regular array.

You can make use of [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to locate the key.

Comment: Thanks @Rvanlaak, we can get next but can't get previous ?

Comment: If you've found the key, then the previous one is `key-1` ?